# Custom block not showing

Tags: blocks, 10

I created a custom block module (nothing fancy, just an A-Z list and a taxonomy list for navigation), this worked fine in D8 & D9, now since upgrading to D10 it only shows when logged out, when logged in, it still writes a debug message to the Apache errorlog from the build() function, so I know the code is being called and I can dump the content to the log, I just get no display of the output. I have a few paths including . Log out and the block is displayed again.

All the answers I can find are for the block not displaying and requiring a login, this works fine until I login.

I'm outputting to the "hero" region and the region is displaying OK, just without my block content.

Any suggestions on what to look for?

Comment: Yes, all good, but surely if it was incompatible, it would fail regardless of logon?

Comment: Could be caching with your theme.  Try with one of the unmodified core themes and see if you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Does the block have caching metadata? It’s not absolutely required: I’m just asking. Perhaps you should show the code.

Comment: main element of build is

`$build = [
            '#theme' => 'hopnavigation_block',
            '#commons' => $commons_menu,
            '#lords' => $lords_menu,
            '#az' => $az,
            '#constituency' => $con_az,
        ];
        return $build;`

`public function getCacheMaxAge(): int
    {
        return 0;
    }`

Comment: Please put code samples in the Question. It's difficult to format code in comments, and the Question should contain everything necessary for a fact-based answer.

Comment: Are there browser console errors?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely an answer, but I put the same block into claro theme and all was good, the theme in use was a temporary testing theme so will create new one via starterkit so issue is resolved, even if the actual question was not answered. Testing theme was a clone of Olivero taken from 9.4 using the work at https://github.com/mherchel/olivero-subtheme if that helps others.